# How should I load properties for spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am looking for best approach for loading binding and binder properties for spring cloud stream. I am able to load properties from application.properties and application works fine. I do not want to use application.properties or yaml file. Is there any other option to load properties from config server.